# Warning messages while building Apache server

Tags: apache-2.2, centos5, rpm, make, specfile

I am building Apache server 2.4.6 from source and am not sure about a few warning messages I received during the rpm build process.  The build completes OK and everything seems fine..BTW, this is on CentOS 5.5...

During the make install process in the spec file (%install):

```
/home/johnm/dev/project1/install/linux/BUILD/httpd-2.4.6/srclib/apr/libtool --silent --mode=install install mod_authn_file.la /home/johnm/dev/project1/install/linux/tmp/usr/local/apache2/modules/

libtool: install: warning: remember to run `libtool --finish /usr/local/apache2/modules'
```

What is this warning message about?? remember to run libtool --finish ??

Also, I see this:

```
libtool: install: warning: `/home/johnm/dev/project1/install/linux/BUILD/httpd-2.4.6/srclib/apr-util/libaprutil-1.la' has not been installed in `/usr/local/apache2/lib'
```

I am building Apache in a temp directory but libtools seems to be looking in the wrong place (/usr/local/apache2/lib instead of /home/johnm/dev/project1/install/linux/tmp/usr/local/apache2/lib).  This seems like something I can blow off??

In my specfile I set DESTDIR to /home/johnm/dev/project1/install/linux/tmp where the install files are placed:

```
%install
export DESTDIR=%{buildroot}
make install
```

Both messages appear numerous times during the make process.  When I install the rpm on the system, everything appears to work without problems..Thinking I can ignore these messages??? or am I missing something important??

Comment: Are you writing your own RPM spec file?!

Comment: Yes.  Doing so to take care of some custom installation files and configurations.

Comment: Why don't you just use the existing spec file from Fedora, then? This will save you a lot of headaches.

Comment: Also, putting configuration in your RPMs is "doing it wrong" - you really need to use a real configuration management system for this.

Comment: I am building for a CentOS 5.5 installation target.  Would the Fedora spec file work?? If so, how/where do I get a copy of the spec file?

Answer (score 1):

I was missing way to many important items by trying to use my own spec file which caused the problem I was seeing above.

I found the best way to build Apache was to take the ***httpd.tar.gz*** file and use the httpd.spec file that is included. I basically followed the steps located here:

http://ramblin-dude.blogspot.com/2013/04/compiling-rpm-for-httpd-on-rhel-57.html

The problem of `libuuid-devel` being unavailable for ***CentOS 5.5 or 5.7*** is also addressed in the blog too.  Which is basically use `e2fsprogs-devel` and modify ***httpd.spec*** file to point to this instead of `libuuid-devel`.

Using these directions, I was able to get a rpm built which would install and work without any errors in the log file.